# bash - Argument list too long

Tags: bash

I have ~5k files that I wish to unzip.

```
2:13:35 2017-01-16 $ unpigz *.gz
-bash: /usr/local/bin/unpigz: Argument list too long
12:13:40 2017-01-16 $ unpigz -r *.gz
-bash: /usr/local/bin/unpigz: Argument list too long
12:15:45 2017-01-16 $ gunzip *.gz
-bash: /usr/bin/gunzip: Argument list too long
12:17:56 2017-01-16 $ cp *.gz ~/Desktop/
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

Is there a count limit to the amount of files bash can handle?

Comment: for further reading: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060

Comment: great link share by @ChrisMaes thanks for sharing the info with community

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit is not on the *number* of arguments, but on the combined length of the command line and the environment. (Informally, this means the more strings in your environment, the shorter the command line can be.) This limit is specific to the operating system, not any particular command. To work around this, use `find` to invoke your command repeatedly.

```
find . -prune -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +
```

Here, `gunzip` will be called with as many arguments as possible, and repeatedly until all the matching files have been unzipped.